# Echo Username welcome message in HTML page with PHP

Tags: php, html

I’m pretty much a complete beginner when it comes to PHP and have been having some problems with displaying a Welcome Username message on a HTML page and where to place session_start();  on the page.

Here’s the relevant part of the HTML page: *can one place PHP directly into the page like this?*

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
                <h2><p>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['Username']; ?>.</p></h2>
```

Right at the top of the page (before the HTML) I’ve also put:

```
<?php
  session_start(); 
?>
<!doctype html>
```

(*is this session start in the right place?*)

Not sure if I’m going about this in the right way though :/

Thank you very much for your time; very much appreciate it as well as other helpful replies here.

**EDIT**  Everything works once I changed the pages extension to PHP rather than HTML

Comment: <?php session_start();?>
<!doctype html> try on one space on opening php tag and session start.so have you issue?

Comment: Your session_start looks ok to me and you're echoing out ok too, what is the actual problem, are you getting just 'Welcome,' with no username? Are you sure the session username is being set correctly?

Try a two page test - both with session_start() at the top as you are, on one page have $_SESSION['Username'] = 'test'; then have a link to page two which has echo $_SESSION['Username'];

Comment: what is the extension of file in which you are writing this code?

Answer (score 0):

> can one place PHP directly into the page like this?

Yes. Gathered you use the `<?php ?>` tags, like you did, and the file has the `.php` extension; you can.

> (is this session start in the right place?)

Also correct.

You haven't said what error you're receiving but I'm assuming you'll have a `undefined index 'Username'` error (if you don't, [turn ON php error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and you'll probably see it) this happens because, unless you set the value previously, your `'Username'` index inside the `$_SESSION` array was not defined by `$_SESSION['Username'] = "Mosh Mage"`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct but never forget to store the user name to $_SESSION['username'] or else your it will echo nothing. Before you can store user information in your PHP session, you must first start up the session.

**Note: The session_start() function must appear BEFORE the html tag:** in your case correct as well.

School yourself with sessions at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: @CBroe your comment is nonsense. W3schools is for beginners and he's a complete beginner as what he said.

Comment: None of that invalidates the general criticism about w3schools. And I’m sure you don’t want to make the point that it is OK to teach people stuff that is largely wrong to begin with, just because they are beginners?

Comment: @CBroe  So you are saying that w3schools is wrong to begin with? Why don't you tell that to them so that they'll know and you being better can create your own as if you are better than them? Is it wrong to give them w3schools resource? Then you should've given your own resource